# How do I localize the jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, localization, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I really need a localized dropdown calendar. An English calendar doesn't exactly communicate excellence on a Norwegian website ;-)

I have experimented with the **[jQuery DatePicker](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/datepicker/#localization)**, their website says it can be localized, however that doesn't seem to work.

I am using ASPNET.MVC, and I really want to stick to one javascript library. In this case jQuery.

The ajax toolkit calendar would be acceptable, if only it too would display Norwegian names.

**Update: Awesome! I see I am missing the language files, a not so minor detail :-)**

Comment: Check out [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization "demo") demo. The source gives a good example of how to do it.

Answer (score 196):

For those that still have problems, you have to download the language file your want from here:

> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

and then include it in your page like this for example(italian language):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>
```

then use [zilverdistel's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2905411/377384) :D

Comment: Is this link missing in on the jQuery UI page? I can't find it there http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

Answer (score 81):

I figured out the demo and implemented it the following way:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
  $.extend(
    {'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'},
    $.datepicker.regional['nl']
  )
);
```

I needed to set the default for the dateformat too ...

Comment: this worked for me: `$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["uk"]);`

Answer (score 31):

The string `$.datepicker.regional['it']` not translate all words.

For translate the datepicker you must specify some variables:

```
$.datepicker.regional['it'] = {
    closeText: 'Chiudi', // set a close button text
    currentText: 'Oggi', // set today text
    monthNames: ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo','Aprile','Maggio','Giugno',   'Luglio','Agosto','Settembre','Ottobre','Novembre','Dicembre'], // set month names
    monthNamesShort: ['Gen','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mag','Giu','Lug','Ago','Set','Ott','Nov','Dic'], // set short month names
    dayNames: ['Domenica','Luned&#236','Marted&#236','Mercoled&#236','Gioved&#236','Venerd&#236','Sabato'], // set days names
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mer','Gio','Ven','Sab'], // set short day names
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Me','Gio','Ve','Sa'], // set more short days names
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' // set format date
};

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);

$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

In this case your datepicker is properly translated.

Comment: This answer shows how to add the localization directly, without importing libraries.  This is the method that I needed because I am utilizing jQuery's `$.getScript()` to fetch the main library on Google's hosted API.

Answer (score 13):

```
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    closeText: "关闭",
    prevText: "&#x3C;上月",
    nextText: "下月&#x3E;",
    currentText: "今天",
    monthNames: [ "一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月",
    "七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月",
    "七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月" ],
    dayNames: [ "星期日","星期一","星期二","星期三","星期四","星期五","星期六" ],
    dayNamesShort: [ "周日","周一","周二","周三","周四","周五","周六" ],
    dayNamesMin: [ "日","一","二","三","四","五","六" ],
    weekHeader: "周",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: true,
    yearSuffix: "年"
  });
```

the i18n code could be copied from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Answer (score 10):

**1.** You need to load the jQuery UI i18n files:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js">
</script>
```

**2.** Use `$.datepicker.setDefaults` function to set defaults for ALL datepickers.

**3.** In case you want to override setting(s) before setting defaults you can use this:

```
var options = $.extend(
    {},                                  // empty object
    $.datepicker.regional["fr"],         // fr regional
    { dateFormat: "d MM, y" /*, ... */ } // your custom options
);
$.datepicker.setDefaults(options);
```

The order of parameters is important because of the way [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) works. Two incorrect examples:

```
/*
 * This overwrites the global variable itself instead of creating a
 * customized copy of french regional settings
 */
$.extend($.datepicker.regional["fr"], { dateFormat: "d MM, y"});

/*
 * The desired dateFormat is overwritten by french regional 
 * settings' date format
 */
$.extend({ dateFormat: "d MM, y"}, $.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is example how you can do localization without some extra library.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input.datetimepicker').datepicker({
    duration: '',
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    yearRange: '2010:2020',
    showTime: false,
    time24h: true
  });

  $.datepicker.regional['cs'] = {
    closeText: 'Zavřít',
    prevText: '&#x3c;Dříve',
    nextText: 'Později&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'Nyní',
    monthNames: ['leden', 'únor', 'březen', 'duben', 'květen', 'červen', 'červenec', 'srpen',
      'září', 'říjen', 'listopad', 'prosinec'
    ],
    monthNamesShort: ['led', 'úno', 'bře', 'dub', 'kvě', 'čer', 'čvc', 'srp', 'zář', 'říj', 'lis', 'pro'],
    dayNames: ['neděle', 'pondělí', 'úterý', 'středa', 'čtvrtek', 'pátek', 'sobota'],
    dayNamesShort: ['ne', 'po', 'út', 'st', 'čt', 'pá', 'so'],
    dayNamesMin: ['ne', 'po', 'út', 'st', 'čt', 'pá', 'so'],
    weekHeader: 'Týd',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
  };

  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['cs']);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker-cs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("test");
      $("#test").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd.m.yy",
        minDate: 0,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        firstDay: 1
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Here is your datepicker</h1>
  <input id="test" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Much better due to not having to load another js script

Answer (score 5):

If you use jQuery UI's datepicker and moment.js on the same project, you should piggyback off of moment.js's locale data:

```
// Finnish. you need to include separate locale file for each locale: https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale
moment.locale('fi'); 

// fetch locale data internal structure, so we can shove it inside jQuery UI
var momentLocaleData = moment.localeData(); 

$.datepicker.regional['user'] = {
    monthNames: momentLocaleData._months,
    monthNamesShort: momentLocaleData._monthsShort,
    dayNames: momentLocaleData._weekdays,
    dayNamesShort: momentLocaleData._weekdaysMin,
    dayNamesMin: momentLocaleData._weekdaysMin,
    firstDay: momentLocaleData._week.dow,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' // "2016-11-22". date formatting tokens are not easily interchangeable between momentjs and jQuery UI (https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/890)
};

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['user']);
```

Answer (score 4):

just in case anyone is STILL stuck on this, despite the other answers, I solved this with:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
```

note the extra 'GB'.  After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

This solution may help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

  var options = $.extend({},
    $.datepicker.regional["ja"], {
      dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      highlightWeek: true
    }
  );

  $("#japaneseCalendar").datepicker(options);
});
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Japanese JQuery UI Datepicker</h3>
<input type="text" id="japaneseCalendar"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the property **`data-date-language="it"`**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#TxtDaDataDoc_Val').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group input-append date form-group" 
        id="TxtDaDataDoc" data-date-language="it">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" 
               id="TxtDaDataDoc_Val" runat="server" />
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src=">/js/datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: 0 , dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$.datepicker.regional["vi-VN"] =
              {
                  closeText: "Đóng",
                  prevText: "Trước",
                  nextText: "Sau",
                  currentText: "Hôm nay",
                  monthNames: ["Tháng một", "Tháng hai", "Tháng ba", "Tháng tư", "Tháng năm", "Tháng sáu", "Tháng bảy", "Tháng tám", "Tháng chín", "Tháng mười", "Tháng mười một", "Tháng mười hai"],
                  monthNamesShort: ["Một", "Hai", "Ba", "Bốn", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy", "Tám", "Chín", "Mười", "Mười một", "Mười hai"],
                  dayNames: ["Chủ nhật", "Thứ hai", "Thứ ba", "Thứ tư", "Thứ năm", "Thứ sáu", "Thứ bảy"],
                  dayNamesShort: ["CN", "Hai", "Ba", "Tư", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy"],
                  dayNamesMin: ["CN", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7"],
                  weekHeader: "Tuần",
                  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                  firstDay: 1,
                  isRTL: false,
                  showMonthAfterYear: false,
                  yearSuffix: ""
              };

```
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["vi-VN"]);
```