# Where are the i18n files of jQuery UI datepicker >= 1.11.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internationalization, jquery-ui-datepicker

I downloaded jQuery UI from a custom build (http://jqueryui.com/download) and from http://jqueryui.com/download/all/... but the folder `i18n` is no longer present.

The [Localization](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends) section of the docs still mention the files with the old filenames (like in 1.10):

> Each localization is contained within its own file with the language code appended to the name, e.g., `jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js` for French.

I found the files in [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n), with the new filenames (`datepicker-fr.js` instead of `jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js`), but I didn't find them anywhere else.

Is it a bug in the downloader with the new files structure in jQuery UI 1.11?

Is there somewhere else where we can find the i18n files, except in the GitHub source where it's not really versioned (i.e.: you just get the last files from master without knowing with which version of jQuery UI they are compatible).

Comment: +1 from me. This sort of questions is the reason, I like StackOverflow so much. Thanks, Yann for asking for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The vendor's [upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.11/#overview) mentions the following:

"If you want the complete jQuery UI source files, demos, and tests, you can get them from: 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/releases."

It is here where you will find the files you're looking for, within the appropriate version(s).

I also found the minified file is being hosted by google:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

Comment: Thanks! As they were speaking about demos and tests, it didn't grab my attention, so I missed that sentence. :) (I will upvote tomorrow, I can't right now)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up downloading the files from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n, but I would still like to know if they are available elsewhere.

I have tested them and can confirm they are compatible with my jQuery UI 1.11.1 datepicker.

Comment: Unless this absolutely solves the problem, you should edit your question with the new information. You still seems to have questions left.

Comment: It solves the problem of getting the files, but I'm still curious to know if anyone else had that problem. The original question already had the link to the GitHub files.

Comment: I am the author. I have read that one can answer their own question if it contributes something to the problem. I hope my answer could help other people having this problem. It is a kind of TLDR: the files are there. That said, I was hoping from a more complete answer, and @ne1410s provided just that. :)

Comment: @YannDìnendal: It seems that a few people that review 'low quality posts' are quite eager to reject your answer and repeatedly use the same pre-generated comment to tell you why. Indeed it seems they did not read the edit of your question. So don't worry about it :)

Comment: @Kermit No, I don't have another question to open. As I already said, ne1410s already provided a complete answer.

Comment: @YannDìnendal *"but I would still like to know if they are available elsewhere"* sounds like a question to me.