# import jQuery ui i18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, commonjs, es6-module-loader

Problem: I have jQuery datepicker in react app, which has to be localised in different languages(30 lang). I downloaded all the i18n file from the link (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n) but it has to be included as `<script>` tag.

Question: Is there a way to import this file? using `webpack`and `commonjs`?. I am using es6 `import`. Is there a way to bundle them all and import in the on file?

any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: are you using the webapp in your website? I have answered your question thinking that you are using it for a website. If your problem is different. Let me know so I will edit the answer accordingly

Comment: sorry, looks like you miss understood my question, i know it can be included as `script`tag, but including 30 of this files is bit too much. So it there a way to bundle on the client side?

Comment: Ok I am editing the answer according to your requirement . wait

Comment: Take a look at answer now. I also recommend GRUNTJS which is designed for the same purpose. Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Yes there's a way:

You can create a javascript function that takes the path as a parameter and creates these HTML lines:

```
<script src="js/datepicker-in-all-languages/datepicker-af.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker-in-all-languages/datepicker-ar-DZ.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker-in-all-languages/datepicker-ar.js"></script>

...................and for all other 30 languages................
```

And you'll just have to call this:

```
loadLib("datepicker-in-all-languages/datepicker-af");
loadLib("datepicker-in-all-languages/datepicker-ar-DZ");
loadLib("datepicker-in-all-languages/datepicker-ar");
```

**Edit:**
Also take a loot at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) which is meant for the same purpose.You can setup grunt to watch the folder of the scripts and concat/minify them into a single file, then you just have to include that in your HTML file.:

> **GRuntJS usage(According to their official page):** With literally hundreds of plugins to choose from, you can use Grunt
>   to automate just about anything with a minimum of effort.

**Edit:**

There is also a **minified file of  jQuery ui i18n** which is being hosted by google. You can use it in single `<script>` tag : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js . I found it in answers here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765124/where-are-the-i18n-files-of-jquery-ui-datepicker-1-11-0).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you bundle them all, is it small. You can do that like this:

**Use i18n of jquery-ui datepicker with js ES6**

First import jquery-ui from [jquery-ui-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui-bundle) package (ready for webpack package manager). Then load localization from original [jquery-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui) lib package.

Then set localization of datepickers and finally datepickerize your date inputs.

```js
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
const i18n_cs = require('jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-cs');

$.datepicker.setDefaults(i18n_cs);

$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```