# Validation fails when using dd/MM/yyyy date format with jQuery datepicker.

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My client-side validation fails when I use the dd/MM/yyyy format in my model and dd/MM/yy in jQuery. However if I do the same thing with MM/dd/yyyy and MM/dd/yy the validation goes through without any problems.
What is wrong here? How can I get this to work?

Thanks,
Leo

Comment: Have you cheeked my answer? if it helped you could help others by marking as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker).

Basically you need to localize jquery for the language you want. You do this by including a javascript localization script file that will take care of your formats and currency for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to `jquery.validate` and its inability to parse date string with `"dd/MM/yyyy"` format.

You may check out this for **[reference](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2011/12/14/Globalization-Validation-and-DateNumber-Formats-in-AspNet-MVC.aspx)**.

Comment: I understand that this is a localization issue now, however I am hoping there is a simpler way to force jQuery to use the localization/format that I want, is there a way?

Comment: @RealityDysfunction:- You may find the solution here:- http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization and http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.20/ui/i18n/