# flask admin datepicker localization

Tags: flask, datepicker, localization

**1. Problem**

[image]

This is the datepicker in my flask admin form, all the month and week names are in English, but I want customize the names also the start week number. like this question: [How do I localize the jQuery UI Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker). I searched a lot, but all I got is about how to customize date format in flask.

**2. My code**

```
class Receipt(db.Model):
    delivery_time = db.Column(db.Date,index=True)
```

It's a date column can view and edit in admin form.

Is there any way to config the month、week names ? And how to make the start week number to Monday not Saturday, thanks a lot.

Comment: I find the configuration http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config of daterangepicker, but how to configure it in flask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a quick way to fix this issue, but I know there are better ways to do this. just modify the code in path:lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/static/vendor/daterangepicker.js to below:

```
 this.locale = {
            applyLabel: 'Apply',
            cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
            fromLabel: 'From',
            toLabel: 'To',
            weekLabel: 'W',
            customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
            // daysOfWeek: moment.weekdaysMin(),
            daysOfWeek: ["日","一","二","三","四","五","六"],
            // monthNames: moment.monthsShort(),
            monthNames: ["一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月",],
            // firstDay: moment.localeData()._week.dow
            firstDay: 1
        };
```

Comment: I am not an expert about js, but I guess we could change the locale in monment.js, but I couldn't find it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could change locale globally in your templates, by adding:

```
<script>moment.locale(#YOURLOCALESTRING);</script>
```

This would guarantee that any other script loaded after this one that uses moment would use the global locale setting. You can find more details about setting locale [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/).

Comment: In order to achieve this, you'll have to include the corresponding moment locale file(s) (see https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1875) and override the flask-admin `master.html` template to include them and then enable the desired locale using `<script>moment.locale('locale_code')</script>` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198659/how-to-override-flask-admin-style-for-all-templates).

Answer (score 1):

That code is not a good solution, but it can be helpful:

```
 {% block tail_js %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var el = $('#your_element_id'); // change this selector
      el.daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        timePicker12Hour: false,
        separator: ' to ',
        format: el.attr('data-date-format'),
        locale: {
            format: "MM/DD/YYYY",
            separator: " - ",
            applyLabel: "Выбрать",
            cancelLabel: "Закрыть",
            fromLabel: "От",
            toLabel: "До",
            customRangeLabel: "Custom",
            weekLabel: "W",
            daysOfWeek: ["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"],
            monthNames: [ "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Октябрь", "Сентябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
            firstDay: 1
        },
      });
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

P.S.
Need to add this code into your master.html