# How to override flask_admin style for all templates?

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2, flask-admin

I'm working on simple web application and as for DB display I use **Flask_admin** module.
I would like to apply custom CSS to all my templates e.g. Custom navar with blue border. This is how my index.html template looks like:

```
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
.navbar {
  border-color: #019ced;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
{% endblock %}
```

It works fine but I would like to apply this custom navbar style to *all* templates.

I was trying to do this using master.html

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block head_css %}
{{ super() }}
.navbar {
  border-color: #019ced;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 {% endblock %}
```

and then extending from it in *index.html* without any success.
I guess I could define custom templates for each view inherit from parent and override head section in which I include CSS file with custom navbar but I'm looking for easier way.

Please let me know what is the proper way to define, create and inherit from base template in which I can define my custom CSS. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your master.html file should look like the following:

```
{% extends admin_base_template %}
{% block head_css %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style>
        .navbar {
            border-color: #019ced;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
            border-top: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: An explanation would have been nice: The Jinja2 block element `head_css` offers the possibility to make additional entries in the `<head>` section of the HTML annotation. The intention of the block element is to add stylesheet information here, obviously. Of course this can happen within missing `<style>...</style>`, but you can also include an external file here via `<link href="path/to/your/file.css" rel="stylesheet">` which is cleaner.