# Jquery datepicker localization

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am trying to localize datepicker and I can't fully understand where each code block should be.

In a view I have a script:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-lv.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker(
      $.datepicker.regional["lv"]
    );
  });
</script>
```

It has to be working with this text box in a same view:

```html
<tr>
  <td align="left">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestDate)</td>
  <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestDate, new { id = "datepicker", style = "width:200px"})</td>
</tr>
```

What is missing in that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I localize the jQuery UI Datepicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: I still cant get the point what is missing in my code, i saw that post and tried to do the same.

Comment: Are you have any errors in the web browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "datepicker-lv.js" might not load and you are not aware of this.
With the default settings on an ASP .NET MVC project you will get the following error :

- **Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-lv.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**

You should try do download the datepicker-lv.js, include in your project as the others scripts file and load it from there.