# how can I use 2 languages of datepicker same time

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, calendar, persian

I have a datepicker jquery ui plugin. my default language is Persian. but I want 2 use 2 languages in datepicker same time. it means that I want to show calendar in Persian language as default, but I can switch to Gregorian calendar by click on a button and calendar change from Persian calendar to Gregorian calendar.

how can I do this?

Comment: JQuery UI datepicker _can_ do that... https://stackoverflow.com/a/27675191/87015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [this library](https://github.com/babakhani/pwt.datepicker)
it has a full documentation and very stable which allows you to create a multilingual calendar,I hope it helps you.

[here](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/example/) you can see demos and examples

Comment: @RezaHafezi I am glad to see it was helpful,Nowkaram be ali :D