# Add localization to jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this code that I use to select 2 date in jquery

```
 <script>

  $(function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({minDate: new Date()});
  $('#from').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (date) {
              date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        }
        $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
  }});
  $('#to').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (date) {
              date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        }
        $('#from').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
  }});

   });
    </script>
```

I'd like to insert

```
          $.datepicker.regional['it'];
```

Where I can put in my code? I must do a website in several language so I must change a lot of time the localization code

Comment: Please do some research before posting the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I localize the jQuery UI Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: Thanks I see the page but in my case I don't understand where put in

Comment: Add Zilverdistel code at the beginning of the script i.e., before initializing the datepicker

Comment: or refer the kampageddon answer as he done in the example

Comment: I do 
  $(function() {
    $.datepicker.regional['it'];
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({minDate: new Date()}); ....

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the specific localization file. You can get them from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n). Example below.

Source : [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker)

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/i18n/datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
```